# Why this code is showing "error: label at end of compound statement"?

Tags: switch-statement, label, clang, syntax-error, case

I wanted to check by placing default anywhere in the switch. It should print the default printf statement as no case label is matching & after that default case is checked in the switch. But it's showing the above error.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    char ch='g';
    switch(ch){
        default: printf("Success!\n");
        case 'v':
        case 'h':
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting break; after the case statements.

Comment: Actually, by putting break, it's working fine. My doubt was regarding the fact that if the condition doesn't match any case label, then it should go to the default case, by rules. Even, when, I'm putting the default case at the end, after these two cases, then it's working fine! But, it's not working in this situation & hence I've got the doubt regarding the rule of placing the default anywhere in the switch.